Gparted is not allowing me to add unallocated space in extended partition
GParted is not allowing me to add unallocated space in an extended partition even if I delete my swap.
Below you can see my hard drive's unnalocated space


Jellyfish is not 24. Edit your question and add the proper and complete Lubuntu version number.

You cannot expand/contract an in-use partition, where the LOCK symbol shows a locked partition that cannot be resized. Your picture shows 3 locks (ie. 3 partitions that you can't resize); and doesn't show gparted but shows KDE Partition Manager, plus unallocated space outside of an extended partition  (sda5 & sda6 inside extended partition sda4 can only use space within sda4; not outside of the extended partition in which they exist)

https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.1/3.1.6/kde_partitionmanager.html?highlight=kde%20partition%20manager  is the Lubuntu manual page (22.04) for KDE Partition Manager; until October 2024 anyway (that link will show 24.04's manual then)

You have to have unallocated inside the extended partition. And probably have to unmount swap even if using flash drive or DVD live system. Live installers often mount swap.

One cannot format or resize a disk's partitions while any of the disk's partitions is mounted. When a partition is mounted, the disk's metadata (partition info, cluster allocation info, ...) is cached in the kernel. parted, gparted, or other formatting tools also manipulate the disk's metadata.  Chaos follows.
Boot from another medium, your install disk in "Try" mode or a Live distribution.
Ensure that none of partitions of the target disk is mounted, and that any swap partition is not used. Use df, sudo umount and swapoff. Read man df umount swapoff free.
